# MFSideMenu setLeftViewController unrecognized selector sent to an instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to implement SideMenu feature in my app, but i am taking an exception.

Here is my code;

What is wrong with this code, I am using StoryBoard

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 KASideMenuContainerViewController *container = (KASideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
 UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
 UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
 UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];

 [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
 [container setRightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuViewController];
 [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];

 return YES;
}

-(void)changeController:(UIViewController *)aViewController{
 KASideMenuContainerViewController *containerViewControllar = (KASideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

 [containerViewControllar.centerViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aViewController]];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we need a bit more details. What does `KASideMenuContainerViewController` inherit from? It looks like it may be inheriting from the wrong View Controller. I've never used MFSideMenu, but it looks like your `KASideMenuContainerViewController` should be inheriting from `MFSideMenuContainerViewController` instead of just `MFSideMenu`

Answer (score 0):

@erdemgc

I just downloaded the project from [github](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) and it works like charm. 
Try running the MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard project.